# DialogFlow CX how to declare parameters in the start page?

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-cx

I need to declare a parameter to store username as input in the first message of dialogflow session, "My name is John" will be the first message the user type to dialogflow cx,
I noticed it's not possible to create a parameter on the Start page, is there is a way to detect parameters using EntityType from the first message of the session ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect parameter values from the first end-user input, you can use [intent parameters](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/parameter#intent).

First, create an intent and add training phrases like "My name is John" and similar. [See how the intent may look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yyfp.png).

Then, add an [intent route](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/handler#route) on the Start page and define agent response in fulfillment. [See how the route and a simulator test may look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEJhX.png).

You can also check the [general agent design best practices](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/agent-design) for more information.